# Show Modal Popup window based on Dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Here I have a Dropdown selection with "Create New" option. When User selects "Create New" then it should display Modal Popup window.

This is Dropdown code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownConfigFile"  runat="server" CssClass="selectpicker">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Create New" Value="1" ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Here it is Jquery for opening Popup window,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        //Attach click event to your Dropdownlist
        $("#DropDownConfigFile").change(function () {
            //Get the selected valu of dropdownlist
            selection = $(this).val();
            //If its one then show the dialog window. You can change this condition as per your need
            if (selection == 1) {
                //Show the modal window
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my Modal popup design.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"  align="center" style = "display:contents ">
        <table class="table table-hover small-text" id="tb" border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
        <%--<td class="col-md-4">Index Position</td>--%>
              <th style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: DarkGrey ">Index Position</th>
              <th style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: DarkGrey ">Alpha-Numeric Scramble</th>
              <th style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: DarkGrey ">Packed-Decimal Scramble</th>
        <%--<td class="col-md-4">Type of Scramble</td>
        <td class="col-md-4">Scrambling Required</td>--%>
         </tr>
       </thead>
</div>
```

But unfortunately if I select "Create New" it is not opening a popup. What's wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because you are using `runat="server"`

In this code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownConfigFile"  runat="server" CssClass="selectpicker">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Create New" Value="1" ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

if you inspect the dropdown in your browser you will see its id changed to `"ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownConfigFile"`, So in your script you are using `$("#DropDownConfigFile").change(function () {` which will not work as there is no element with that id and jquery cannot bind the change event to it.

There are 2 solutions for this problem.

**1)** **Set the Client Id mode to static**: to your elements so that you remain with the static id.

Make this changes to both your DropDownList control

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownConfigFile"  runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="selectpicker">
```

With this the Id will remain as is and Jquery will be able to find it and bind the change event.

**2)** **Change your script to use the ClientID .**
 change you Jquery itself to use the ClientID instead ... like below

`$("#DropDownConfigFile").change(function () {` **change this to**

`$("#<%= DropDownConfigFile.ClientID %>").change(function () {`

So now make Jquery read proper ID and so it binds the event..

Comment: Hi sir, every thing working fine but it is displaying complete window. I want to reduce the size of popup window. Is there any chance to reduce the size of window.

Comment: @kiran do you have the same HTML structure as specified in bootstrap site? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using bootstrap. Have you included the bootstrap.js? Along with jquery?

```
$("#select-me").on('change', function() {
  //alert($(this).val());
  if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
  }
});
```

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypegxr4u/)